# Problems opening a notebook in Mathematica

Tags: front-end, formatting

*Reviewers: please see the comments below my answer for additional information on why the edits were made. -bobthechemist*

I have a text file (with a .txt extension) written for *Mathematica*, but opening it does not render the graphics and simulations found in the notebook.  How do I get the original notebook format back?

This problem can occur when downloading a notebook from an internet source; sometimes a notebook or cdf gets saved as a text file and the correct extension gets lost.  Is there a way to programmatically open a text file containing notebook information without resorting to changing the extension?

Comment: `tt = Import["~/test.txt"]`

Comment: change the extension to nb?

Comment: posting the first dozen or so lines from the file might be useful...

Comment: This is not really answerable without more info, optimally the file in question. Please add more detail to save us from too much speculation.

Comment: There ain't such thing as a ".txt file written for Mathematica".

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to guess at what the OP wants.  This code should reproduce the problem as I see it.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}]
Export["test.m", p]
RenameFile["test.m","test.txt"]
```

The file "test.txt" is now a text version of a notebook file that has valid Mathematica code but an extension that will be misinterpreted by Mathematica.  To circumvent this problem, specify the filetype in the `Import`

```
Import["test.txt","NB"]
```

...and all is well.

Comment: bob, this seems like a good interpretation and possibly useful information for future readers.  Would you care to edit the question in an attempt to salvage it, which will put it in the reopen review queue?  If not I shall delete this in routine clean-up.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard let's see what I can come up with

Answer (score 2):

Not sure chris has the right idea. I assume your file is not some exported data, strings, tables, etc. but rather a bunch of commands you basically want to execute from file, right? The `Import` command tends to work with the types of files produced by `Export`. It would probably treat your file as text.

You can use the `Read` or `ReadList` commands. If you use `Read` it will step sequentially through each line of the text file executing each line. If you do `ReadList` it will do them all at once. For example, I create a text file with the following contents:

```
Print["asdf"];
Plot[x,{x,1,10}];
Plot[x^2,{x,1,10}]
x=3;
```

Then when I do `ReadList["C:\\test.txt"]` I will get the following:

```
(* Output:

   asdf
   {Null,Null,[Graphics Object Here],Null}

 :End Output *)
```

The asdf comes from the `Print` command, which is executed and does work. The list is all the output, which includes `Null` for the lines ending with a semicolon. However, the graph of `x^2` does show, because it does not have a semicolon.

Another way to do this might be:

```
While[Read["C:\\test.txt"] != "EndOfFile"]
```

which reads everything quietly -- no output because whatever output there is (be it `Null` or something else), it will just be compared to "EndOfFile" and not returned. That includes the `Print` command, which produces no output either.

After doing any one of these methods, if I ask for the value of `x` I will get `3` as expected.

**Edit**: george2079 suggests changing the extension and opening the file with Mathematica. That too is possible, if all you want to do is turn a .txt file into a .nb file. I'm not sure that's what you want either, but if so, then that works.

Comment: NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookDataPosition[       157,          7]
NotebookDataLength[    117810,       2882]
NotebookOptionsPosition[    115658,       2807]
NotebookOutlinePosition[    116002,       2822]
CellTagsIndexPosition[    115959,       2819]
WindowFrame->Normal*)

(* Beginning of Notebook Content *)
Notebook[{

Cell[CellGroupData[{
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"(*", " ", 
   RowBox[{
    RowBox[{"HOMEWORK", " ", "2"}], " ", "-", " ", 
    RowBox[{"LUCIE", " ", "DAVIDOV\[CapitalAAcute]", " ", "1"}]}], " \
", 
   "*)"}], "
",

Comment: This is a short excerpt I want to open with Mathematica, maybe it becomes more clear now what i want ;)
I want to execute this commands but it doesn't work by executing, i think i have to convert this file first but don't know how...

Comment: or this one too:

Cell[CellGroupData[{

Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"RSolve", "[", 
  RowBox[{
   RowBox[{"{", 
    RowBox[{
     RowBox[{"a", "[", "n", "]"}], "==", 
     RowBox[{
      RowBox[{"6", " ", 
       RowBox[{"a", "[", 
        RowBox[{"n", "-", "1"}], "]"}]}], "-", 
      RowBox[{"9", 
       RowBox[{"a", "[", 
        RowBox[{"n", "-", "2"}], "]"}]}], "+", "8"}]}], "}"}], ",", 
   RowBox[{"a", "[", "n", "]"}], ",", "n"}], "]"}]], "Input"],

Comment: Those are the contents of your file?? Seems like that's just a .nb file that seems to be renamed .txt. You should follow george2079's suggestion and rename it with the correct file extension...

Comment: i renamed it but it's still the same content, can't get any results out of it when i run it...

Comment: How did you create this file? Do you have the entire file available somewhere? I still think -- even now, knowing that the file might contain chunks of a valid notebook file -- that there isn't enough information to help you. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: i actually downloaded it from some university webpage, so it's lecture material which i would like to open but it doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: It is entirely possible the file is corrupt or otherwise not able to be opened. If you downloaded it from a website, it might have changed the file extension, but if changing it back to .nb doesn't work, I don't know what else to tell you. Also, it looks like this is someone's homework. Maybe you shouldn't be messing with it in the first place?